# Is there a way to read the files off of a hard drive that was previously in a Western Digital MyBook External HDD Enclosure?

Tags: windows-7, usb, external-hard-drive, data-recovery

My external hdd unfortunately took a tumble the other day and it landed square on the usb connector, breaking the socket off so it was inside the enclosure just rattling around, leaving me unable to connect it to a computer. I thought perhaps it would be as simple as taking the hdd out of the enclosure and connecting it to my motherboard via SATA, but it said the entire hdd was "unallocated space". Is there something I can do to get my data other than getting my enclosure repaired?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately if you are getting unallocated space warning, chances are the tumple actually damaged the drive or caused corruption of the file table. Continuing to connect it to a windows machine might actually end up making the data unrecoverable by inevitable writes that will happen to it by the OS trying to communicate with it. So before you take any more action on it, get yourself a data recovery tool, such Ontrack EasyRecovery from one of the more reliable recovery people and give it a go and see if there is anything to even recover off it. Also Western Digital has their own hardware testing tool call Data Lifeguard diagnostic (http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?groupid=810&sid=3&lang=en) run that first to make sure the drive is ok, and then worry about the data. If the drive is dead, short of a professional recovery, you are pretty much out of luck.